# using the click event to fade in and fade out hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to learn the fundamentals of jquery and would love some advice on how to achieve the following.

When I click on the 'Drop down' link a hidden list of links is faded in, when I click on any part of the page except the #innerList tag then the hidden list fades out or if I click on one of the hidden links then the list fades out also.

My current effort is here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/b6XC4/

It would be great to get some advice on how I can achieve this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the JS to following you get the described effect.

```
var innerList = '#innerList';

    $(innerList).hide();

    $('a.mainButton').click(function(e) {
        $(innerList).fadeIn('slow');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(e){
        $(innerList).fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

Also I suggest changing the  tag href's to "#" for testing or remove the href altogether.

Created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6XC4/54).

Comment: good point with the # links. I didn't mention that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do (i missed out what you mean with 'hidden links' does it mean that it must hide also when you click on  the links?);

```
var innerList = $('#innerList');

    innerList.hide();
    $('a.mainButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       innerList.fadeIn('slow');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

$(document).click(function(e){
   var id= $(e.target).closest('ul').attr('id');
    if (id !== 'innerList' && innerList.is(':visible')){
        innerList.fadeOut('slow')
            }else{
                e.preventDefault();
            }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/b6XC4/40/

Comment: Won't stop event propagation in all of the browsers.

Comment: The confusion was about the fact that jQuery uses the same name "stopPropagation" that is not supported in all browsers. It seems however that they have simply used the same name and made it cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (much smaller code)

```
var $innerList = $('#innerList').hide(); //Set $innerList to the DOM object so that it only needs to be found once. Also hide the object. "hide()" returns self so we can combine the two in one line.
$('ul.dropDown').click(function(e) {
    $innerList.fadeToggle('slow');
    e.stopPropagation(); //stop the click event bubbling back to the document which would also fire the function below (undoing what this function just did)
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $innerList.fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/b6XC4/52/)

This should be cross-browser due to using jQuery

Comment: Won't stop event propagation in all of the browsers.

Comment: Which browsers won't it work in? Works in FF and IE. jQuery documentation about [stopPropogation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) doesn't say anything about it being non-cross browser, which is one of the things that jQuery is supposed to help with.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, the jQuery does override the stopPropagation function.

Comment: @Zanfa Thanks for acknowledging. Can you please remove your downvote? (I assume it was you as there are no other comments)

Comment: Only if you edit your answer, I can change my vote. Otherwise it's locked.

Comment: @Zanfa let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1628/discussion-between-grezzo-and-zanfa)